# 'foreman start' is stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, heroku

I have a locally developed Rails application.  It is very simple, with no database but only a controller that accesses Facebook data and renders them in view.  By the way, gem **RestGraph** is used.

Before I push this application to heroku, I used foreman start to test it.  Since I was using WEBrick before I need to install 'thin' gem and create a Procfile which reads:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RACK_ENV -p $PORT
```

an '.env' file seems also required, which reads:

```
RACK_ENV=development
PORT=3000
```

The 'config.ru' file is generate by rails, which reads:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Myapp::Application
```

Now I entered 'foreman start', but all I get is one line:

```
15:33:18 web.1     | started with pid 27143
```

The server will not boot. And if I force terminate it, the error is:

```
/usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:141: [BUG] rb_sys_fail() - errno == 0
```

Which is not very helpful.

Comment: Is your application called foreman or are you using [The Foreman](http://theforeman.org/) rails app to controll Puppet?

Comment: The application is just 'Myapp', and no, 'foreman start' is used to test Rails application before deploying on heroku, as described here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#webserver

Comment: It will be this 'Foreman' - https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

Answer (score 1):

It may be that instead of being "stuck," your log is just being buffered: [foreman only shows line with “started wit pid #” and nothing else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717198/foreman-only-shows-line-with-started-wit-pid-and-nothing-else)

I solved that issue by adding

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

to config.ru

Then you might get more helpful feedback from Foreman.

Comment: This works for me. When I do ctrl-C on the stuck foreman, I got the rest of the lines spitted out too.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little over complex.  From looking at a couple of apps I have I have the following in my procfile:

```
bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT
```

I also don't have a `.env` file in these instances.

One thing worth noting is that Foreman will ignore the port you pass in most of the time, it likes to sit in a port range higher than 5000